# TypeError: client.getAsync is not a function - redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I want to use redis as caching for my database. I wrote the following code and it is giving me the error:

> ```
> const offerData = await client.getAsync(offerID)
>                                ^ TypeError: client.getAsync is not a function
> ```

My current code :

```
const redis = require('redis')

// Connect to the Redis server
const client = redis.createClient()

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('[PASS]'.green + ' Redis Connected')
    require('bluebird').promisifyAll(redis)
})

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
 const offerData = await client.getAsync(offerID)

    let link
    if (offerData) {
        // If the offer data is in Redis, parse it and assign it to the link variable
        link = JSON.parse(offerData)
    } else {
        // If the offer data is not in Redis, get it from the database and store it in Redis
        link = await Offers.findOne({_id: offerID})
        if (link == null) return res.sendStatus(404)
        client.set(offerID, JSON.stringify(link))
    }

//Do some
})
```

How can I fix this? Tried that `promisifyAll` but no luck

Comment: I don't see `getAsync` in the docs. Why do you assume it exists?

Comment: @Konrad found that on a tutorial

Answer (score 1):

*getAsync* is not a function of *redis* module.
You can use [redis-promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis-promisify) module which offers this method.

Here is a sample ref for you bellow:

```
const redis = require('redis-promisify')

// Connect to the Redis server
const client = redis.createClient()

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  const offerData = await client.getAsync(offerID)
  // rest of the code
})
```

Comment: Getting this error : Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: Make sure your Redis server is running and on port 6379, if it's on a different port you need to pass it like this 
const client = redis.createClient({
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379,
  db: 0
})

Last but not least, read the docs.